# Как подгрузить интерфейс из другого файла?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qlayout

Я хотел немного разделить интерфейс от основного кода.

Cоздал два класса - `Design`, который находяится в файле **Design.py**, и `MyWindow`, который находится в файле **Main.py**.

В классе `Design` создаются виджеты, которые должны попасть в главное окно приложения. Мне нужно как-то импортировать создание виджетов в класс `MyWindow`.

Может быть, можно подгрузить создание виджетов из файла **Design.py** в **Main.py**?

**Design.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Design(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Text')

        box.addWidget(btn)
```

**Main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import Design


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный импорт

```
from Design_ import Design
```

Создайте экземпляр класса

```
self.design = Design()
```

Добавьте в макет

```
layout.addWidget(self.design)
```

---

**Main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
#import Design_
from Design_ import Design    # поменял на `Design_`, потому что у меня такое имя модуля `Design` уже было 


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)


        self.design = Design()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.design)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MyWindow')
    window.resize(400, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Design_.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Design(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Text - Design')

        box.addWidget(btn)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]